# Help me convert C++ structure into C#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling, dllimport

I am completely new to C#, and need help converting a C++ structure to C#.  The C++ structure is given as:

```
#define QUE_ADDR_BUF_LENGTH 50
#define QUE_POST_BUF_LENGTH 11

typedef struct
    {
    const WCHAR *streetAddress;
    const WCHAR *city;
    const WCHAR *state;
    const WCHAR *country;
    const WCHAR *postalCode;
} QueSelectAddressType;

typedef struct
    {
    WCHAR   streetAddress[QUE_ADDR_BUF_LENGTH + 1];
    WCHAR   city[QUE_ADDR_BUF_LENGTH + 1];
    WCHAR   state[QUE_ADDR_BUF_LENGTH + 1];
    WCHAR   country[QUE_ADDR_BUF_LENGTH + 1];
    WCHAR   postalCode[QUE_POST_BUF_LENGTH + 1];
    } QueAddressType;
```

I cannot make changes to the C++ structure as they are defined by the API I am attempting to interface with.  Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Here is more information, the function in the dll I am attempting to call is declared the as follows:

```
#ifdef QUEAPI_EXPORTS
#define QueAPIExport __declspec(dllexport)
#elif defined QUEAPI_SERVER
#define QueAPIExport
#else
#define QueAPIExport __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef uint32 QuePointHandle;

QueAPIExport QueErrT16 QueCreatePointFromAddress
    (
    QueSelectAddressType*   addr,   // in:  Address data to search on.
    QuePointHandle*         point   // out: Handle to selected point. Must be closed with QueClosePoint.
    );
```

Here is how I have defined the DllImport:

```
[DllImport("QueAPI.DLL", EntryPoint = "QueCreatePointFromAddress")]
public static unsafe extern QueTypesnConst.QueErrT16 QueCreatePointFromAddress(QueTypesnConst.QueSelectAddressType *address, uint *point);
```

EDIT2:
The following code blocks were the solution to the problem:
For the Structures:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct QueSelectAddressType
{
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string streetAddress;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string city;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string state;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string country;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string postalCode;
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct QueAddressType
{
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=51)]
    public string streetAddress;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 51)]
    public string city;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 51)]
    public string state;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 51)]
    public string country;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 12)]
    public string postalCode;
};
```

For the DllImport:

```
[DllImport("QueAPI.DLL", EntryPoint = "QueCreatePointFromAddress")]
public static extern QueTypesnConst.QueErrT16 QueCreatePointFromAddress(ref QueTypesnConst.QueSelectAddressType address, ref uint point);
```

Comment: Do you care about the sizes or can you just use a string?

Comment: I do believe the sizes matter, but I cannot be certain

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following definition

```
public partial class NativeConstants {

    /// QUE_ADDR_BUF_LENGTH -> 50
    public const int QUE_ADDR_BUF_LENGTH = 50;

    /// QUE_POST_BUF_LENGTH -> 11
    public const int QUE_POST_BUF_LENGTH = 11;
}

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct QueSelectAddressType {

    /// WCHAR*
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string streetAddress;

    /// WCHAR*
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string city;

    /// WCHAR*
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string state;

    /// WCHAR*
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string country;

    /// WCHAR*
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string postalCode;
}

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct QueAddressType {

    /// WCHAR[51]
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=51)]
    public string streetAddress;

    /// WCHAR[51]
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=51)]
    public string city;

    /// WCHAR[51]
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=51)]
    public string state;

    /// WCHAR[51]
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=51)]
    public string country;

    /// WCHAR[12]
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=12)]
    public string postalCode;
}
```

Comment: @JaredPar: You may need to include the SizeConst in the attributes...i.e. SizeConst = NativeConstants.QUE_ADDR_BUF_LENGTH

Comment: @tommieb75, it does include the SizeConst modifier on the struct's which need it.  You have to scroll to the right due to the incredibly long code

Comment: I have made an edit to the original post, which may help in determining the answer.

Comment: This worked.  Thank you for your help.  I will update the post with the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
public struct QueSelectAddressType
{
    public readonly string StreetAddress;
    public readonly string City;
    public readonly string State;
    public readonly string Country;
    public readonly string PostalCode;

    public QueSelectAddressType(string street, string  city, string state, string country, string code)
{
    this.StreetAddress = street;
    this.City = city;
    this.State = state;
    this.Country = country;
    this.PostalCode = code;
}
}

public struct QueAddressType
{
    char[] streetAddress = new char[QUE_ADDR_BUF_LENGTH + 1];
    char[] city = new char[QUE_ADDR_BUF_LENGTH + 1];
    char[] state = new char[QUE_ADDR_BUF_LENGTH + 1];
    char[] country = new char[QUE_ADDR_BUF_LENGTH + 1];
    char[] postalCode = new char[QUE_POST_BUF_LENGTH + 1];
}
```

Comment: @taylonr: I don't think this would work as you cannot have an initializer in a struct...

Comment: Not sure, MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288208(VS.71).aspx) simply says: 
A struct cannot have an initializer in the form: base (argument-list).  But I'm not doing that.  Granted the one above by JaredPar is better... I think he submitted while I was typing